# WHERE clause in MySql statement breaking page

Tags: mysql

I have selected all the appropriate columns for this statement. When I change WHERE user_id = $user, and the $user is a number, that works. However it doesn't seem to like the username letters. User is a valid column in my table and 'john' does exist. What am I doing wrong?

```
$user = 'john';

// Set the timestamp from the current system time
$time = time();

// Put our query together:
$query =    "UPDATE table set 
                    `time` = {$time}
                    WHERE user = {$user}";
```

Comment: Do you wrap $user in single quotes?

Comment: Nope that doesn't change anything

Comment: Single quotes and not backtics. user='$user' is not working???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, here:

```
 `user_id` = {$user},
 `time` = {$time}
  WHERE user = {$user}";
```

You're pointing twice to the same value $user, one for id, one for user, Are you sure you haven't defined that value twice in your JS scripts? Try giving different names to each value and that could help

Comment: I realised that then took '`user_id` = {$user},' out of my statement. Still doesn't work!

Comment: It's the $user variable you need to worry about, it sounds like it's coming in as a number, try renaming $user='John' to $userName='John'

Answer (score 0):

do you miss a "," after "{$time}"?

Comment: No that it doesn't need comma

Answer (score 0):

Check the data in the *user* column, I have a feeling it's numeric. If you insist on using the username the look in MySQL documentation of a function to convert username to user-number and use it in your WHERE clause.

Comment: My 'user' column is VARCHAR. Ok - i'll have a look at that. Thanks